# Show and update nested attributes in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an :item model with nested attributes from :item_galleries showcasing multiple images. I'm able to create an item with the nested images but having issues with editing.

I want to be able to show each image attached to the item and able to edit each one.

Who ever helps me gets a VIRTUAL COOKIE OR PIE!

For the "Item Form View":

```
<%= f.fields_for :item_galleries do |p| %>
  <%= p.label :image %>
  <%= link_to "Edit Attachment", edit_item_gallery_path(p) %>
  <%= p.file_field :image, :multiple => true, name: "item_galleries[image][]" %>
<% end %>
```

I'd like to show the image right next to the edit attachment link.

This is the edit function in the items_controller:

```
  def edit
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item_galleries = @item.item_galleries.all
  end
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end
```

Currently the link that edit_item_galleries_path(p) brings me to is `"http://localhost:3000/item_galleries/%23%3CActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007ffce80b2358%3E/edit"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the image just use an image_tag.

```
<%= p.label :image %>
<%= link_to "Edit Attachment", edit_item_gallery_path(p) %>
<%= image_tag p.image if p.object.image.present? %>
```

To fix your edit link: you want to pass the id and not the whole form builder helper to your url. Using `p.index` will return the id of the element if its persistend and a generated uid if it is not yet persisted.

```
<%= link_to "Edit Attachment", edit_item_gallery_path(p.index) %>
```

So the whole code will look like this:

```
<%= p.label :image %>
<%= link_to "Edit Attachment", edit_item_gallery_path(p.index) %>
<%= image_tag p.image if p.image.present? %>
```

Edit: 
i fixed the image, thanks for pointing that out in the comments.

Comment: I tried this, but get the error "undefined method `image' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fcc61ed2a08>"

Comment: I also get an error when using p.index "Couldn't find ItemGallery with 'id'=0". So all I did was p.index+1 and it worked. Just need to get the other issue sorted.

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks for pointing in the right direction. This fixed it <%= image_tag p.object.image if p.object.image.present? %>

Comment: Glad i could help - fixed the image part in my post. But regarding your edit link - you should just only display it when the object is persisted -> that should fix the bug.